Measurement elements
Do you know how I can draw this and implement it in an electrical circuit?


I not think that exist the symbols in your picture.

If the given symbology exists.

You've posted code in previous questions, sometimes after it is requested. And several of your questions concern code for circuits, so it isn't obvious what you expect here exactly.

Those are symbols used on electro-mechanical  instruments to indicate the type of measurement principle, they are not circuital symbols. So no, they are not in circuitikz; on the other hand, they should be easy to draw. Show your attempt (so we have an usage case example) and somebody'll help.

The issue is simple to make definitions of drawings or pics and place them on a table, the difficult thing is to help someone who has a very bad attitude who has been given good answers and does not even accept them, and even responds and rewards himself.

This is the answer:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% Simbolo de Bobina Movil
\begin{tikzpicture}[name=BM]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
    \draw (-0.4,0) --++ (0,4) arc (180:0:2) coordinate(A) --++ (0,-4) --++ (0.4,0) --++ (0,4) arc (0:180:2.4) --++(0,-4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hspace{2cm}
%
%Simcbolo de Hierro Movil
\begin{tikzpicture}[name=HM]
    \draw[fill= black] (0,0) rectangle (1,4);
    \draw[fill= black] (2,4) circle (0.3cm);
    \draw[fill= black] (2.4,-1) circle (0.3cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] (2.4,-1) -- (-0.5,0) -- (1.5,1) -- (-0.5,2) -- (1.5,3) -- (-0.5,3.5) -- (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Taking every single element of your table and include like a graphic without to draw nothing. I have drawn a generic circuit to have an idea.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[npn](npn){};
    \draw (npn.C) to[R,l=$R$] ++(0,2) node[vcc]{};
    \draw (npn.C) to[short,*-] ++(2,0) node[anchor=west](led){};
    \draw (npn.E) node[ground]{};
    Add your symbol.
    \node at (led) {\includegraphics[width=0.7cm]{example-image-c}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



@downvoter My was only an idea. To the usual hater: disappear.

+1 :) Greetings

@Dr.ManuelKuehner I thank you for your comprehension. My sincerest regards.
